# Undefined symbol: SSL_library_init with Syslog-ng

Tags: debian, openssl, syslog-ng

I have OpenSSL installed from source and linked the `GLIB_LIBS` and `GLIB_CFLAGS` to the correct directories during configure and configured `with-SSL`

When I try to start syslog-ng (Version 3.6.4) on Ubuntu Server 14.04, I get the following errors:

```
[2017-04-20T12:39:18.252222] Error opening plugin module; module='afsocket', error='/linux1/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslog-ng-crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init'
[2017-04-20T12:39:18.253205] Error opening plugin module; module='dbparser', error='/linux1/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslog-ng-crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init'
[2017-04-20T12:39:18.255387] Error opening plugin module; module='afsocket-tls', error='/linux1/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslog-ng-crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init'
[2017-04-20T12:39:18.256429] Error opening plugin module; module='cryptofuncs', error='/linux1/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslog-ng-crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init'
[2017-04-20T12:39:18.256964] Error opening plugin module; module='syslog-ng-crypto', error='/linux1/lib/syslog-ng/libsyslog-ng-crypto.so: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init'
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL libraries are highly dependent on versions and their ABI changes frequently.

Either your maintain different versions of ssl libraries on your system, or you have to (re)compile also binaries that depend on your new openssl libraries.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying I need to reinstall OpenSSL from source?

Comment: What I am saying is that you if you overwrote/delete the ssl libraries that syslog-ng is counting on with new versions, you have to reinstall also it from source.